# Why is my Firebase CLI version different than what I just installed with npm?

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I'm updating firebase tools using

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

and it outputs

> - firebase-tools@9.3.0

However, when I run firebase --version or firebase tools --version I'm getting:

> 7.15.1

When I do 'which firebase' I'm only getting the following path:

> /usr/local/bin/firebas

Why would there be a discrepancy with the versions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `npm` in your path is updating a different `firestore` that you see in /usr/local/bin.  Run `which npm` to see which one you're running.  I would guess that it's not in /usr/local/bin.  You should probably put that path to npm in your path **before** /usr/local/bin, and also remove the `firebase` in /usr/local/bin to use only the one that's updated by your npm.  (And maybe also do some thinking about how you got a `firebase` in /usr/local/bin in the first place, in order to prevent that from happening again.)

Comment: Excelent thank you, not sure how I installed firebase originally but I've removed it from /usr/local/bin and getting the right version now.  Thanks Doug.