# Could not save data to emulator - "Did not find any running emulators for project "

Tags: firebase, gcloud, firebase-tools

when I running fireabse. i am running the following command :

```
    "serve": "firebase use dev && firebase emulators:start --import=./emulator-data"
```

i have added data but I can not now save the data to the emulator
and I have got :

```
Error: Did not find any running emulators for project test-dev.
```

the command that i run is :
`firebase emulators:export ./emulator-data`

how can I fixed it ?
i verified the project is connected on gcloud and everything was working as it should

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot this error you can follow the following steps as mentioned in [Github_issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4283#issuecomment-1074399270)

> 1. ran sudo firebase emulators:export ./exported and got a new error
>    file not found!!
> 2. control c the running firebase process then ran it
>    again and got the same file not found error!!
> 3. command quit both
>    terminal windows
> 4. deleted the log files
> 5. ran the firebase emulator
>    again with "sudo firebase emulators:start --import ./data
>    --export-on-exit" (works)
> 6. opened another terminal window and "sudo firebase emulators:export ./exported" and it worked!!

Sometimes this issue can occur due to  installations of firebase-tools path and npm and node paths are different. You may have a look at the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66192839/15774176).

For additional  information on emulators, you can follow the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure).

Comment: @yuksi Posted an answer, is it helpful?